# Multiplication proctoring program

Tags: java, loops

I am working on a project for school and am at a loss for ideas after searching online and looking at loop flow charts, and different methods to accomplish what is required.

The requirements are:

1. Generate two, 1 digit integers, and ask the user to find the product of said two.
2. If wrong, print "No. please try again. " & prompt the user for input to try again forever until correct.
3. If correct, print "Very good! " & prompt question with two new integers.

I am confused as to what kind of loops to use, and how to order them in order to serve their purpose.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Program utlizes scanner
import java.security.SecureRandom; // Program utlizes SecureRandom

public class WaringComputerAided {

static void callNumbers() { //method to generate random numbers
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = rand.nextInt(10); //generates random integer #1
        int num2 = rand.nextInt(10); //generates random integer #2
            System.out.printf("How much is "+num1+" times "+num2+" ?: "); // Asks question
                int sum = (num1 * num2);
        }

static void tryAgain() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("No. Please try again. ");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = rand.nextInt(10); 
        int num2 = rand.nextInt(10);
        int sum = (num1 * num2);    

    do { // Asks question first time, and asks new question when user inputs correct answer
        callNumbers(); //Generates numbers and asks new question
        int answer = input.nextInt(); // Asks user for input
        } while(answer == sum);

    if (answer != sum) { // When answer incorrect
        tryAgain();
        } 

    if (answer == sum) { // When answer is correct
        System.out.printf("Very good! "); 

        }
    } // End method main
} // End class product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `callNumbers` method is not returning anything change it to int and return the `sum`

```
static int callNumbers() { //method to generate random numbers
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
//        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = rand.nextInt(10); //generates random integer #1
        int num2 = rand.nextInt(10); //generates random integer #2
        System.out.printf("How much is "+num1+" times "+num2+" ?: "); // Asks question
        int sum = (num1 * num2);

        return sum;
    }
```

At the **`tryAgain`** method we need to change the logic if it is incorrect then just call main method to repeat the procedure

```
static void tryAgain() {
        System.out.printf("No. Please try again. ");
        main(new String[]{});
    }
```

We want to get the correct answer so we save it to a new variable so then we can compare it with the number user has entered

```
sum = callNumbers();
```

The **do while** logic

```
do {
             sum = callNumbers();
             answer = input.nextInt();
            if (answer != sum) { // When answer incorrect
                tryAgain();
            }
            if (answer == sum) { // When answer is correct
                System.out.printf("Very good! ");

            }
        } while(answer == sum);
```

All the code

```
    import java.util.Scanner; // Program utlizes scanner
import java.security.SecureRandom; // Program utlizes SecureRandom

public class WaringComputerAided {

    static int callNumbers() { //method to generate random numbers
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
//        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = rand.nextInt(10); //generates random integer #1
        int num2 = rand.nextInt(10); //generates random integer #2
        System.out.printf("How much is "+num1+" times "+num2+" ?: "); // Asks question
        int sum = (num1 * num2);

        return sum;
    }

    static void tryAgain() {
        System.out.printf("No. Please try again. ");
        main(new String[]{});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = rand.nextInt(10);
        int num2 = rand.nextInt(10);
       int sum = 0;
        int answer = 0;
        do {
             sum = callNumbers();
             answer = input.nextInt();
            if (answer != sum) { // When answer incorrect
                tryAgain();
            }
            if (answer == sum) { // When answer is correct
                System.out.printf("Very good! ");

            }
        } while(answer == sum);




    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
How much is 9 times 1 ?: 23
No. Please try again. How much is 6 times 0 ?: 6
No. Please try again. How much is 4 times 3 ?: 2
No. Please try again. How much is 7 times 1 ?: 7
Very good! How much is 0 times 0 ?: 0
Very good! How much is 4 times 4 ?:
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!! I really appreciate it. Thank you for explaining the logic as well as it was confusing to me at first, but it makes sense now :)